# How to loop through results and delete all but the newest item?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a DB with players and events.  One player has many events.  Event has a creation date.

We want to clean up the DB I need to write SQL (using MySQL) that, for each player will delete all his events except the newest one.

So how do I do this sort of looping and custom deletion in SQL:

```
select all PLAYERS from PLAYER
for each PLAYER
delete all EVENTS except where EVENT.creationDate is the newest one
```

?

ANY help is greatly appreciated on this!

## more detail

PLAYER table has PLAYER_ID varchar(100)

EVENT table has EVENT_ID bigint, PLAYER_ID varchar(100), CREATED_AT (bigint)

Comment: More details on the fields in the events table will help us help you... Such as the name of the player ID column and whether or not the table has a decent unique key.

Comment: Hi Jamie, added more details!  Thanks!

Comment: delete events e1 where e1.created_at != ( select max(e2.created_at) from events e2 where e1.player_id = e2.player_id ) to test run select * from events e1 where e1.created_at != ( select max(e2....) learn sql a lot simpler and cleaner then java

Comment: thanks, how do i wrap this delete call inside a select * from player so it does it for every player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do Multiple-table syntax of delete, combined with a subquery to create reference table where you could check the newest creationDate:

```
DELETE FROM `events` 
  USING `events` 
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT playerId, MAX(creationDate) AS `maxCreationDate` 
      FROM `events` GROUP BY playerId) AS `referenceTable` 
    USING (`playerID`) 
  WHERE `events`.`playerId` = `referenceTable`.`playerId` 
    AND `events`.`creationDate` != `referenceTable`.`maxCreationDate`;
```

Tested with these tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM players;
+----------+------------+
| playerId | playerName |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Andy       |
|        2 | Buddy      |
+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM events;
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| eventId | playerId | creationDate        |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
|       3 |        1 | 2011-12-06 01:49:58 |
|       1 |        1 | 2011-12-07 01:49:20 |
|       2 |        1 | 2011-12-08 01:50:03 |
|       1 |        2 | 2011-12-07 01:50:06 |
|       2 |        2 | 2011-12-08 01:50:00 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the result looks good.

```
mysql> DELETE FROM `events` 
    -> USING `events` 
    -> INNER JOIN (
    -> SELECT playerId, MAX(creationDate) AS `maxCreationDate` 
    -> FROM `events` GROUP BY playerId
    -> ) AS `referenceTable` 
    -> USING (`playerID`) 
    -> WHERE `events`.`playerId` = `referenceTable`.`playerId` 
    -> AND `events`.`creationDate` != `referenceTable`.`maxCreationDate`;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM events;
+---------+----------+---------------------+
| eventId | playerId | creationDate        |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
|       2 |        1 | 2011-12-08 01:50:03 |
|       2 |        2 | 2011-12-08 01:50:00 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks, i'd like to try it with a select first to ensure the right stuff will get deleted -- but when i change DELETE FROM to SELECT * FROM, the USING seems to cause syntax errors -- any tips?

Comment: If you want to test it first, change `DELETE FROM events USING` to `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: I'm trying your query in SQL Explorer but it's telling me there's syntax errors around the USING keyword.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports multi-table delete as an extension to SQL.  You can do joins without using subqueries.

```
DELETE e1 
FROM Players p 
INNER JOIN Events e1 ON p.player_id = e1.player_id
INNER JOIN Events e2 ON p.player_id = e2.player_id
WHERE e1.event_id < e2.event_id;
```

We want to delete the row `e1` if another row `e2` exists with a higher event_id, and the same player.  Naturally, the most recent event for a given player can never pass the condition for `e1`.

I'm assuming event_id increases as creationDate increases, and it's better to choose that since it will never result in a tie.

Comment: @Algorithmist: Sorry, the query in your answer appears to delete from the wrong table.  The question is about deleting events, not players.  Also, MySQL doesn't like it when you DELETE from a table and SELECT from it in one statement -- it doesn't know what kind of lock to use.

Comment: FYI, this worked for small amounts of data, but with 20,000+ records, the query seems to get exponentially slower.  Maybe it's comparing each record's id with 20,000 other ids for every row, so it doesn't scale well?  In the end I used @Riyono's solution below.  Thanks.

Comment: This query, like most joins, would depend on having the right index.  I suggest a compound index on Events over the two columns (player_id,event_id) in that order.

Answer (score 1):

in the for each section :

**SELECT Events.creationDate FROM Events WHERE Events.player == (each player) ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1;** *// get you the first event*

Put it in a var like DateLastEvent or so

**DELETE Events WHERE Events.creationDate < DateLastEvent:**

*//except if strictly at the same date/time it will delete all others*

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea how I'd wrap this in a "for each player" loop so the "(each player)" is set appropriately?

Comment: you have no var on SQL so if you dont want to put any code here you must imbricate SQL req

Answer (score 0):

> Delete from Players where event_id not in 
>      (select event_id from players where event_date in (select min(event_date) from players group by player_id))

This is the simple query which would also work.

Comment: I actually want to delete from events, not players.